# How to run appium desktop from command line

Tags: appium

I have a question related to Appium Desktop 1.6.4. How to run a session by command line? It is possibility to run this application with paramaters related to session or run saved session (Tab Presets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, as of now.., Appium Desktop wont run in command line. It has been cleanly mentioned in their page

> **Appium Desktop does not run in a shell or a command-line environment**

To get more information kindly check here,[Appium-Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop).

Hope this helps you. Thanks.